# mac in app purchases - receiving store kit responses different thread

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, in-app-purchase

I'm testing out in app purchases for my mac app, and I've noticed that the selectors productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: and paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: are getting called on a background thread (not the main/ui thread) when I request products or try to make a purchase.

I haven't seen any documentation warning about this, since that would mean updating UI from within these methods should not be done.

Has anyone else run into this?  Should I just be calling performSelectorOnMainThread: within these methods to update the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue as it appears to behave just like an asynch call using NSURLConnection. I solved my particular issue by using the NSObject method call "performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUnitlDone:" Probably setting up NSNotification to be caught on the main thread of ViewController or WindowController would work as well.